# How can I call the cli function in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I want to CLI function in C#.
I want to call `Set_Test` function by using `List<T>` in C#.

**CLI Source**

```
void Api::Set_Test(array<Test>^% _Test2)
```

**C#**

```
List<Test> Test3 = new List<Test>(5);
Test3.Add(...)
...
Api.Set_test(ref Test3)  --> Error
```

**Error code** : it is not converted from `List<Test>` to `Test[]`.

How can I call the function?

Comment: List isn't an array. Use ".ToArrray" for Test3 and pass it into your function.

Answer (score 2):

Jane,

Its a little unclear, however, your Set_test is after an array and you wanted to work with a list.

Normally then you would do `Api.Set_Test(Test3.ToArray());`